# Android Studio - горячие клавиши для подключения библиотек

Tags: android-studio

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Перешел с Eclipse на Android Studio, но не могу разобраться: каким образом производится автоматическое подключение необходимых библиотек? В Eclipse это решалось комбинацией клавиш Ctrl+Shift+O, в Android Studio данная комбинация не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае удобней поставить галку чтоб все было на лету.

> Идём в File | Settings | IDE Setting | Editor | Auto Import и ставим
>   флажок у пункта Add unambiguous imports on the fly.

и еще [плюшечки](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/tips-studio.php)